# Subgroups of product groups and representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Recall that a *family* of  subgroups of $G$, denoted by $\mathcal{F}$,  is a collection of subgroups of $G$ that is closed under taking subgroups and conjugation.

Denote by $\Sigma_m$ the group of permutations of the set **m**$=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, that is the symmetric group of degree $m$. Let $\mathcal{F}^{G,\Sigma_m}$ be the family of subgroups $L\leq G\times \Sigma_m$ such that $L\cap \{e\}\times \Sigma_m= \{(e,e)\}.$ The projection function
$\mathrm{pr}_1:G\times\Sigma_m\to G$ has kernel
\begin{align}
\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{pr}_1)&=\{(g,\sigma)\in G\times\Sigma_m | \ \mathrm{pr}_1(g,\sigma)=e\} \\
&=\{(e,\sigma)|\ \sigma\in\Sigma_m\} \\
&=\{e\}\times\Sigma_m
\end{align}

So, a subgroup $L\leq G\times\Sigma_m$ belongs in the family $\mathcal{F}^{G,\Sigma_m}$ if and only if the restriction to $L$ of the projection, *i.e.*,  $\mathrm{pr}_1|_{L}: L\to G$,  is an injection.

There is a bijective corresponce between the family $\mathcal{F}^{G,\Sigma_m}$ and the set of all representations, of all subgroups of $G$, on the finite set **m**$=\{1,\ldots, m\}$, that is, all group homomorphisms $\phi:H\to \Sigma_m$ for every $H\leq G.$

My question is : Is there a subfamily of the family $\mathcal{F}^{G,\Sigma_m}$ that contains precisely the actions of the group $G$ on **m**, that is, group homomorphisms $\phi:G\to \Sigma_m$ and for every subgroup $H\leq G$ with inlcusion $i:H\to G$ we only allow restrictions of group actions of $G$ to $H$, that is, we only allow $i^*\phi: H\to \Sigma_m$ ?

Any input would be helpful